# Searching a 3D array for closest point satisfying a certain predicate

Tags: algorithm, search, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for an enumeration algorithm to search through a 3D array "sphering" around a given starting point.

Given an array `a` of size `NxNxN` where each `N` is `2^k` for some `k`, and a point `p` in that array. The algorithm I'm looking for should do the following: If `a[p]` satisfies a certain predicate, the algorithm stops and `p` is returned. Otherwise the next point `q` is checked, where `q` is another point in the array that is the closest to `p` and hasn't been visited yet. If that doesn't match either, the next `q'`is checked an so on until in the worst case the whole array has been searched.

By "closest" here the perfect solution would be the point `q` that has the smallest Euclidean distance to `p`. As only discrete points have to be considered, perhaps some clever enumeration algorithm woukd make that possible. However, if this gets too complicated, the smallest Manhattan distance would be fine too. If there are several nearest points, it doesn't matter which one should be considered next.

Is there already an algorithm that can be used for this task?

Comment: You are mixing the task and the solution. And the part of solution that you are fixed on does not fits the question. Who have said that going by one cell steps you'll find the closest "good " cell? On the contrary, cells of next distance layer will mostly be separated.

Comment: @fafl: I had a look at R-tres but I don't see how it could be used to find the nearest `q` for a given `p`. AFAIU, search in a R-tree decides for a certain branch and will then find the nearest point within that branch, which isn't necessarily the nearest point within all branches if you decide for the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for increasing squared distances, so you won't miss a point. This python code should make it clear:

```py
import math
import itertools

# Calculates all points at a certain distance.
# Coordinate constraint: z <= y <= x
def get_points_at_squared_euclidean_distance(d):
    result = []
    x = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(d)))
    while 0 <= x:
        y = x
        while 0 <= y:
            target = d - x*x - y*y
            lower = 0
            upper = y + 1
            while lower < upper:
                middle = (lower + upper) / 2
                current = middle * middle
                if current == target:
                    result.append((x, y, middle))
                    break
                if current < target:
                    lower = middle + 1
                else:
                    upper = middle
            y -= 1
        x -= 1
    return result

# Creates all possible reflections of a point
def get_point_reflections(point):
    result = set()
    for p in itertools.permutations(point):
        for n in range(8):
            result.add((
                p[0] * (1 if n % 8 < 4 else -1),
                p[1] * (1 if n % 4 < 2 else -1),
                p[2] * (1 if n % 2 < 1 else -1),
            ))
    return sorted(result)

# Enumerates all points around a center, in increasing distance
def get_next_point_near(center):
    d = 0
    points_at_d = []
    while True:
        while not points_at_d:
            d += 1
            points_at_d = get_points_at_squared_euclidean_distance(d)
        point = points_at_d.pop()
        for reflection in get_point_reflections(point):
            yield (
                center[0] + reflection[0],
                center[1] + reflection[1],
                center[2] + reflection[2],
            )

# The function you asked for
def get_nearest_point(center, predicate):
    for point in get_next_point_near(center):
        if predicate(point):
            return point

# Example usage
print get_nearest_point((1,2,3), lambda p: sum(p) == 10)
```

Basically you consume points from the generator until one of them fulfills your predicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is pseudocode for a simple algorithm that will search in increasing-radius spherical husks until it either finds a point or it runs out of array. Let us assume that `condition` returns either true or false and has access to the x, y, z coordinates being tested and the array itself, returning false (instead of exploding) for out-of-bounds coordinates:

```
def find_from_center(center, max_radius, condition) returns a point
  let radius = 0
  while radius < max_radius,
     let point = find_in_spherical_husk(center, radius, condition)
     if (point != null) return point
     radius ++
  return null
```

the hard part is inside `find_in_spherical_husk`. We are interested in checking out points such that

```
dist(center, p) >= radius AND dist(center, p) < radius+1
```

which will be our operating definition of husk. We could iterate over the whole 3D array in O(n^3) looking for those, but that would be really expensive in terms of time. A better pseudocode is the following:

```
def find_in_spherical_husk(center, radius, condition)
   let z = center.z - radius // current slice height
   let r = 0 // current circle radius; maxes at equator, then decreases
   while z <= center + radius,
     let z_center = (z, center.x, point.y)  
     let point = find_in_z_circle(z_center, r)
     if (point != null) return point
     // prepare for next z-sliced cirle
     z ++
     r = sqrt(radius*radius - (z-center.z)*(z-center.z))
```

the idea here is to slice each husk into circles along the z-axis (any axis will do), and then look at each slice separately. If you were looking at the earth, and the poles were the z axis, you would be slicing from north to south. Finally, you would implement `find_in_z_circle(z_center, r, condition)` to look at the circumference of each of those circles. You can avoid some math there by using the [Bresenham circle-drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm); but I assume that the savings are negligible compared with the cost of checking `condition`.

Comment: In-layer-finding  will be MUCH more simple if you'll work not with distances, but with their squares. Square is a growing function, so you'll lose nothing.

Comment: @Gangnus true, but a small time savings overall. The greatest benefit is that it avoids potential precision-related errors by sticking to integer, lossless math

Comment: Of course. That is because I use that way for distance checking for 39 years already.

Comment: @tucuxi: Thanks, your algorithms seems to work so far with a simplier "`find_in_z_square`" function which checks if the point is wihin the surface of a square around the center instead of a circle. I'm a bit worried that, if a circle algorithm like Bresenham is used, there could be some points missed between two adjacent radiuses. Could that happen with that algorithm?

Comment: @siracusa No, there should be no such concern. As long as you really examine the points that satisfy that their distance is `>= r` and `< r+1` (or, to avoid floating-point and square-roots, their distance-squared is between r^2 and (r+1)^2 - as Gangus notes), there is really no way for points to be either lost or double-counted. Bresenham simply avoids extra math, but IIRC does so by keeping an error term strictly between the required bounds.

Comment: @tucuxi Ahem. I propose to compare squares, but not "r^2 and (r+1)^2". Rather x^2+y^2 against M, with M increasing by 1. Only that way we won't have a false solution.

Comment: @Gagnus can you please explain how/why there can be overlap between passes in a radius-incremented-by-one scenario, but no overlap in a squared-radius-incremented-by-one scenario? You could increment that radius it by any number >0 and <=1 -- non-overlap is guaranteed by every point being included in one, and only one pass. Not by using smaller increments as you get further away.